# Explain this apparent contradiction in Angular JS validation

Tags: angularjs

Given this markup...

```
<form name="myForm">
       <input type="text" name="myField" required ng-model="field1" />
</form>
```

I can access the validity of the field with the following script...

```
myForm.myField.$error.required
```

However if my code is within a directive then I need the directive to be dependent on ngModel and I need to access the validity of the field like so...

```
$ngModel.$valid.required
```

So the first method makes it look like the validation is applied to the form element where as the second makes it look as though the validation is defined on the model. The first seems more accurate because I can circumnavigated the validation if I edit the model directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a form a name, such as `myForm`, Angular publishes the [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController) onto the current $scope using that name, so in your view `myForm` is the form's FormController (which is really `$scope.myForm`).

When you give a form element a name, such as `myField`,  Angular publishes the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) onto the FormController, so in your view `myForm.myField` is the form element's ngModelController (which is really `$scope.myForm.myField`).

In a directive, if the directive does not define a new scope, it can access the FormController and the ngModelControllers the same way, via the scope... or (the more common case) ... if the directive is defined on a particular form element, it can use `require: 'ngModel'` to get reference to that form element's ngModelController.

In your two examples, `myForm.myField...` and `$ngModel...` (I assume $ngModel is the 4th argument to your link function) are both accessing the form element's ngModelController.

(What is `$ngModel.$valid.required`?  ngModelController has a `$valid` property, but it doesn't appear to be an object hash.  So I would expect just `$ngModel.$valid` to be used.)

Comment: I found $ngModel.$valid to be an object hash. It had a property called 'required' that was set to either true or false.

Comment: I think Angular JS has made the same mistake that ASP.net WebForms made. They've put the validation on the UI instead of on the model. With ASP.net MVC, the UI validation code is generated from attributes defined on the model properties.